# Datagridview cellclick event for next rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two different button on datagridview as shown in snapshot on first click the action is performed correctly but on second click if sactioned or unsanctioned is click all the rows below the clicked till the end perform same action.

```
void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Ignore clicks that are not on button cells.
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Status Cancel"].Index)
    {
        statusNotSanctioned(e);
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        GetData();
        return;
    }

    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Status Confirm"].Index)
    {
        confirmLeave(e);
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        GetData();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //if click is on new row or header row
    if( e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex || e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    //Handle First Button Click
    if( e.ColumnIndex  == dataGridView1.Columns["Your First Button"].Index)
    {
        //Do the stuff for first button click
        MessageBox.Show("First Button Clicked");
    }

    //Handle Second Button Click
    if( e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Your Second Button"].Index)
    {
        //Do the stuff for second button click
        MessageBox.Show("Seccond Button Clicked");
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried both the solution but same problem continue.

Comment: @user3089887 please be sure you are using the code correctly and then for example if instead of `Do the stuff for first button click` you put `MessageBox.Show("First Button Clicked");` and instead of `Do the stuff for second button click` you put `MessageBox.Show("Second Button clicked");` what do you receive?  (Like in the answer)

Comment: @user3089887 what was the result of test?

Comment: I have tried to use messagebox the smae thing continue. for 1 confirm or cancel click it goes in infinite loop. I have getDataMethod() which load datagridview after every click Is it because of GetData Method?

Comment: @user3089887 You can comment it to see if it will be solved or not. Surely The solution will work if you provide a stand alone test. but in your case maybe the problem somewhere else.

Comment: @user3089887 What is important to me is if you learnd how to handle the click event on a button or not?

Comment: I have problem with click event of button it goes infinite time on single click?

Comment: @user3089887 It cant go infinitive, if you create a simple sample, then you will see click on a cell of DataGridView never goes infinitive by itself. Have you ever seen for example click on a normal button goes infinitive?

Comment: @user3089887 And by the way, What do you mean when you say it goes infinitive? What do you mean when you say it clicks all the rows below the clicked and till the end perform same action. By seeing which symptom toy say that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how the action can be performed correctly at all, since both `if` conditions in the snippet are wrong. They should be

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Status Cancel"].Index)
{
    // ...
}
if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Status Confirm"].Index)
{
    // ...
}
```